# Is it possible to feed the pretrained Inception model (tensorflow 2.0/Keras) with 2D grayscale images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

According to Keras 2.0 documentation, in relation to the input shape of the images that can be fed to the pretrained inception model:

> input_shape: optional shape tuple, only to be specified if include_top
>   is False (otherwise the input shape has to be (299, 299, 3) (with
>   'channels_last' data format) or (3, 299, 299) (with 'channels_first'
>   data format). **It should have exactly 3 inputs channels**, and width and
>   height should be no smaller than 75. E.g. (150, 150, 3) would be one
>   valid value.

However, I am dealing with grayscale image which are 2D. How I should deal with this situation?

Comment: Just convert the image to color images having identical R, G and B channels. But don't expect the network to behave well on colored images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the grayscale image 3 times for a pseudoRGB image

```
import numpy as np
# img=np.zeros((224,224))
```

If your image is of shape length 2, only width and height you will first need to add an extra dimension:

```
img = np.expand_dims(img,-1)
```

The you repeat this last dimension 3 times:

```
img = np.repeat(img,3,2)
print(img.shape)
# (224,224,3)
```